# Toggle Camera using AVCaptureSession iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avcapturesession

I'm recording video through **AVCaptureSession**,while recording when i change/toggle camera session became end/terminated and method `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL` called. 
is there any way to  continue recording and toggle camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Its not possible to toggle camera within same recording session. You can not record single video with two camera.

if you  want result in single video, Try appending video files at the end. You can check [following](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/15/video-composition-with-ios/) blog for that.